# How did my function enter an if statement if it wasn't supposed to VBA?

Tags: vba, if-statement

I have a function that did something fairly odd. It entered in to an if statement despite the condition not being met for said if statement. Here is an image of the debugging screen:
[image]

Note that 'diameter' is an input to the function ByVal as double, and that the value I'm sending in is in fact 0.0762.

Very possible it's something stupid I missed in which case sorry, but otherwise I am intrigued and would love to hear your thoughts on it either way. Thanks!

```
Public Function ErrorMessages(F_T As Double, pressure As Double, ByVal diameter As Double, t As Double, x As Double, xmax As Double, _
   h As Double, error As Double, i As Integer) As Boolean


    diameter = CDec(diameter)           'Because 0.076199999999999999999999999 <> 0.0762...
    ErrorMessages = False

        If diameter <> 0.0762 And diameter <> 0.1524 And diameter <> 0.2032 And diameter <> 0.3048 _
      And diameter <> 0.4064 And diameter <> 0.6096 Then
            MsgBox ("Error: This pipe diameter is not available from the cool pipe guy")
            ErrorMessages = True
        End If


End Function
```

Comment: Please post your code so that we can assist you.  (An **image** of code is impossible to debug!)  Without code to test, I can only guess at the fact that either `diameter` or `0.0762` isn't **exactly** 0.0762 - e.g. it might be 0.0761999999999999999999999999 and only displayed as 0.0762.

Comment: @YowE3K yup I think you're right, just realized 0.0762 is a calculated value (from a division), is there an easy workaround for this to fix my if statement that you know of?

Comment: Use `CDec` to convert to a decimal data type. `Double` is more prone to floating-point rounding errors.

Comment: That said you should really [edit] your post and paste the relevant code into the actual post, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: @Mat'sMug The Cdec solved the problem. Thank you kindly! I won't bother with the upload of the code since the problem is resolved, but I will keep that in mind in the future!

Comment: If you leave a question with the code being just an image, I will dv it.  It sets a bad example to other users.

Comment: Ahh - but I would have dved it **as well**.  BTW - a common way of dealing with tests of equality on `Double` variables is to check the absolute difference is very small - e.g. `If Abs(diameter - 0.0762) > 1E-10 And ...`  (And it looks like whoever **did** dv it has noticed the edit and removed their dv!)  (And, BTW, instead of doing `MsgBox "abc"` `MsgBox "xyz"`, consider doing `MsgBox "abc" & vbCrLf & "xyz"`.)

Comment: Always use `Round(variable,digits)` for comparing Double/Single. Earlier I encountered **100% is not equal to 1** because of the far rounding off.